# Ruby Array Initialization

Tags: ruby

I need to know the technical difference between these 2 statements and why it behaves like that:

```
arr = Array.new(3, "abc")
=> ["abc","abc","abc"]
arr.last.upcase!
=> "ABC"
arr
=>["ABC","ABC","ABC"]     # which is **not** what I excepted
```

On the other hand:

```
arr = Array.new(3){"abc"}
=> ["abc","abc","abc"]
arr.last.upcase!
=>"ABC"
arr
=> ["abc","abc","ABC"]     # which is what I excepted
```

Comment: From the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#class-Array-label-Creating+Arrays): *"Note that the second argument populates the array with references to the same object. Therefore, it is only recommended in cases when you need to instantiate arrays with natively immutable objects such as Symbols, numbers, true or false."*

Comment: I'd add, just in case you're a Java programmer, that Ruby strings are mutable objects, not like Java ones.

Comment: I know this is a duplicate (has been asked numerous times already), but SO search is failing me. Anybody have a link at hand?

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I've had success using Google, with "site:stackoverflow.com" in the search string, when SO's search engine doesn't turn up what I'm looking for.

Comment: [Ruby Array](https://gist.github.com/shanshaji/a5dac2cc28a2f346aff6d6a8c45ae147)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arguments are always evaluated prior to a method call whereas a block is evaluated only during the method call at a timing controlled by the method (if it is ever evaluated).

In your first example, the argument `"abc"` is evaluated once before the method `new` is called. The evaluated object is passed to the method `new`. The exact same object is used in the all three elements of the created array. Modifying one means modifying all of them.

In your second example, the block `{"abc"}` is evaluated each time a new element is generated for the array. The three elements in the created array are different objects.